# Remember folder window sizes on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows

How do you make Windows 7 to remember each folder sizes?

Now if I resize a window, the next window will have the same size.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Most people expect "an explorer window" to always open with the same size they set it to, and that's what they went for, I guess. I don't think folder-specific window size settings are stored anywhere.

Comment: try this: http://www.sevenforums.com/free-developer-programs-projects/40916-shellfolderfix-manage-folder-window-positions-size.html

Comment: @magicandre1981, oh thanks, i could accept that as an answer, if that really is the only way to do it.

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, this is an known issue in Windows 7. On [sevenforums](http://www.sevenforums.com/free-developer-programs-projects/40916-shellfolderfix-manage-folder-window-positions-size.html), an user posted  tool called **ShellFolderFix** which tries to fix this:

> This is an app to make Windows 7 explorer folder windows remember
>   their size and position.